# Spring Expression Language в коде и тестах

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit

Прошу подсказать по использованию SpEL-выражений в коде и тестах.
У меня в конфигурации некоторые Bean'ы создаются по условию, в зависимости от конфигурации.
Использую @ConditionalOnExpression, например в таком формате

`@ConditionalOnExpression(value = "${my.property.enable} == true")`

Это работает в коде без проблем. В зависимости от того, какое значение свойства выставлено.
Однако, когда я пытаюсь поднять контекст приложения в тестах, то получаю исключение

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on ru.my.package.MyConfigurationClass.jacksonMessageConverter
...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: EL1041E: After parsing a valid expression, there is still more data in the expression: 'lcurly({)'
...
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: EL1041E: After parsing a valid expression, there is still more data in the expression: 'lcurly({)'
```

В документации (https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.2.9.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#expressions) указан другой способ использования SpEL в аннотациях к Bean'ам. Если исходить из этого, то моё выражение должно иметь следующий вид

`@ConditionalOnExpression(value = "#{ systemProperties['my.property.enable'] == true }")`

В таком виде тесты не падают, однако в основном коде такое выражение почему-то не работает (всегда возвращает false)

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл решение, используя другую аннотацию, которая в данном случае подходит лучше

```
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "my.property.enable", matchIfMissing = CONSTANT_VALUE)
```

но это не решает основной вопрос по синтаксису @ConditionalOnExpression

Comment: А в тестовом профиле `my.property.enable` определено? Спринг, если не находит свойство, подстановку не стирает. Соответственно, SpEl потом падает.

Comment: Можно Спрингу сказать, что использовать, если свойство не найдено. Например, `${my.property.enable:false}` или даже `${my.property.enable:}`. Только это само по себе опасная практика, потому что маскирует ошибки вроде опечаток.

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov Спасибо, возможно и есть проблема в том, что в тестах не подтягиваются свойства из тестового профиля. Почему - выясняю. Я столкнулся с этим на следующих этапах. А по поводу значения по умолчанию как ${my.property.enable:false}, я в моём случае всё же использую его в параметре matchIfMissing. Для меня тем более это важно, так как пользователь приложения может и не определять это свойство, тогда приложение должно работать с настройкой по умолчанию. У меня есть класс конфигурации, который резолвит все свойства. Пришлось сделать значение по умолчанию публичной константой.